# Still having issue with revertFunc() not a function in v2.1

Tags: fullcalendar

I am still seeing "TypeError: revertFunc is not a function" when calling it from eventDrop with version 2.1:

```
                eventDrop: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc ) { //drag from one date to another - update ride

                    if(event.status && event.status.toString() == "C") {
                        revertFunc();   
                    }
```

I've checked all of the resources here and elsewhere for similar issues, but nothing seems to work. The bottom line is that it's funcitonally working (i.e. "reverting"), but obviously I would like not to throw an error.

Comment: Your argument list is wrong. See http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/

Comment: Thanks! There was a lot of competing argument list info out there.

Answer (score 4):

Your argument list is wrong.

From the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/):

```
function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {}
```